# Magento 2 - How to set chown and chmod for root folder and sub folder in linux (centos 6.5)

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions

In Magento 2,  How to **set chown and chmod for root folder and sub folder** in linux.
My OS system is the CentOS 6.5.
please, guide me step by step.

P/S: When use this command "find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;" is this security ?

Comment: It's not help my issue.B/c my os is Centos

Comment: I ran this command "find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;" and then get error "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

Comment: You need to run `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` notice the backslash at the end of the command

Comment: Yes, you are right !

Comment: When use this command "find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {}  \;" is this security ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the details of Magento 2 permissions in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html